# Animating width/height of SVG image with jQuery displays improperly in Firefox

Tags: jquery, firefox, animation, svg

I am encountering a potential bug while using jQuery 1.7.1 to animate the height of an SVG image. I want the image height to shrink to 0 while maintaining the same width. The following is a minimum working example of what I'm doing, and it works perfectly in Chrome and Safari. EDIT: as of Chrome 17, Chrome exhibits the same behavior as Firefox, described below; it's necessary to set `preserveAspectRatio="none"` to get the desired behavior. Apparently the former behavior in Chrome was a bug (described in [this bug report](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=34521)).

```
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var flip_timer = setInterval('flip()', 1000),
        flip = function() {
          var height = 64,
              width = 96,
              image = $('img');

          image.animate({'height': 64, 'width': 0}, 200, 'linear', function() {
                            image.animate({'height': 64, 'width': 96}, 200);
                       });
          };
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <img src="image.svg" style="height:64px;width:96px;" /> 
</body>

</html>
```

However, in Firefox, the width changes as well as the height: it seems to be keeping the the same proportions (aspect ratio), so when I shrink the height, it shrinks the width as well. (Similar behavior occurs when I try changing just the width, but leaving the height the same.)

If I use a PNG rather than an SVG, Firefox works exactly as I expect.

I've also tried various versions of jQuery, back to 1.2.6, and saw no change in any of this behavior. I tried not setting the unchanging parameter, and I also experimented with passing in strings vs integers, or reversing the order that the width/height were passed in, and saw no changes.

Is this a bug in Firefox, a bug in jQuery, or something else? (I was hoping to gather some more feedback here before filing a bug report, in case this is already well-known or in case I made a mistake somewhere.) Thanks!

EDIT: here are the contents of the SVG I've been testing with, in case it helps:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 15.0.0, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 0)  -->
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
     width="80px" height="60px" viewBox="0 0 80 60" enable-background="new 0 0 80 60" xml:space="preserve">
<linearGradient id="SVGID_1_" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="40.0005" y1="60" x2="40.0005" y2="4.882812e-04">
    <stop  offset="0" style="stop-color:#0D0D0D"/>
    <stop  offset="1" style="stop-color:#000000"/>
</linearGradient>
<rect fill="url(#SVGID_1_)" width="80" height="60"/>
<path fill="#FFFFFF" d="M53.568,60c-0.006-2.305-0.082-5.051-0.234-8.261c-0.158-3.344-0.648-6.569-1.475-9.676
    c-0.826-3.108-2.164-5.764-4.012-7.965c-1.85-2.203-4.504-3.304-7.965-3.304c-3.383,0-5.979,1.101-7.787,3.304
    c-1.811,2.201-3.127,4.856-3.953,7.965c-0.826,3.106-1.318,6.332-1.476,9.676c-0.151,3.205-0.229,5.959-0.235,8.261H9.675
    c0.019-8.13,0.825-14.935,2.419-20.414c1.611-5.546,3.794-9.972,6.549-13.275c2.752-3.304,5.959-5.664,9.617-7.08
    c3.657-1.416,7.531-2.124,11.622-2.124c4.168,0,8.083,0.708,11.741,2.124s6.883,3.776,9.676,7.08s4.996,7.729,6.609,13.275
    C69.5,45.064,70.303,51.872,70.322,60H53.568z"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: What's in image.svg? Does it have a viewBox attribute defined on the outer svg element?

Comment: It does, in fact. I just updated my question with the contents of image.svg. Does having viewBox defined change things? (If so, is there a potential workaround?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The viewBox on the outer svg element which is being used as an image provides the image with an aspect ratio that it will keep. To work around this you can either:

a) remove the viewBox altogether on the outer image svg element although that may change what's visible in the image

b) add preserveAspectRatio="none" to the outer svg image element which will force the aspect ratio of the viewBox to be ignored and allow the container to force a size

c) add preserveAspectRatio="defer" on the outer svg image element which will allow the container's preserveAspectRatio to be used but since you're using an html image element as the container (rather than an svg image element) this might not work. On the other hand if it does it allows the image to keep its aspect ratio when displayed standalone but use the container's when displayed as an image.

Comment: This worked great, thanks! I removed viewBox and it seemed to have no effect other than making the animation work as intended. Do you know if either Firefox or Chrome/Webkit are displaying the SVG incorrectly, or is this an area where there are simply different interpretations of the standard?

Comment: Firefox is displaying the image correctly. The default value of preserveAspectRatio (i.e. if you don't set it) is xMidYMid per http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/coords.html#PreserveAspectRatioAttribute so the UA should enforce a fixed aspect ratio by default

Answer (score 1):

Try changing this...

```
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
     width="80px" height="60px" viewBox="0 0 80 60" enable-background="new 0 0 80 60" xml:space="preserve">
```

With this...

```
<svg version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 1 1" preserveAspectRatio="none">
```

It should adapt to the size you state in `img style='...'`

Comment: Thanks for the help! I couldn't trim it down quite as drastically as you suggested (or the image wouldn't show up at all), but setting `preserveAspectRatio="none"` seemed to do the trick for the animation.